# stop .htaccess mod_rewrite in a directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have copied some code (for Wordpress permalinks) into my .htaccess file in the root directory.
All has been working fine. This is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've now created a new directory that I want to password protect using .htaccess.
I've set that up (using a ht.access file in the directory I want to protect) but when I try to browse to the password protected directory I get re-directed to the main sites index.php page.

I'm guessing I need to add something to the .htaccess file in the root directory? Is this correct and if so could someone tell me the code I need to add?

Comment: After an afternoon of searching and testing, I finally found a solution that worked, though I'd post it in case anyone else has the same problem. I added the following before my existing .htaccess code

    #This is what I added
    ErrorDocument 401 /failed.html
    #end added part

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myPasswordDirectory/(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/failed.html$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

Answer (score 11):

Put this to your password protected subdir .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Disable rewriting
RewriteEngine Off

</IfModule>
```