# .htaccess RewriteRule exclude folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made a TLP system for PHP with .htaccess. And I want to exclude the /admin folder (in root folder).
I've got this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
```

When I enter the /admin directory, it says: /admin/?url=admin.
But I don't want it to request the ?url=admin.

Does somebody know how to exclude the /admin folder?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need any rewrites in your admin area, the simples way is to place a .htaccess file in the admin directory saying `RewriteEngine Off`.

Another option would be to add the following above both rewrite rules:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/`.

Comment: First of all, many thanks for answering my question for one part. When I got to www.domain.com/admin/ it doesn't say ?url=admin, but when I go to www.domain.com/admin it does say www.domain.com/admin/?url=admin.
Maybe you do know how to fix that problem?

Comment: `RewriteEngine Off` doesn’t do anything, if a rewrite has already happened on a higher level.

Comment: As RewriteEngine off does nothing, still the slashes aren't workign for this TS.

Comment: For me this is the simplest and bestest answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143068/stop-htaccess-mod-rewrite-in-a-directory

Answer (score 2):

Change your .htaccess, add the following lines:

```
//Ignore Admin folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/

//Always add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

You might want to check this URL out, everything explained just fine: http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/